# Mongoose models gone right after init function exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

*EDIT*
I think I've found the problem...
I tried using process.env.PWD somewhere and it all works, except for Mongoose. Deleted it's usage and everything suddenly works. Can someone explain why?
*END EDIT*

On startup, my app does a few things like defining routes and setting up Mongoose.

**/init/db.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    const {url, options} = getCredentials();

    mongoose.connect(url, options);

    // This requires the files that have the schemas in 'm
    loadSchemas();

    console.log(require('mongoose')); // Shows all models
};
```

**Example Schema File (user.js)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    registration_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
    birthdate: {type: Date}
});

mongoose.model('User', User);
```

In `/init/db.js`, a log on `require('mongoose');` still shows all the models and are accessible, right after that function call, a log on `require('mongoose')` shows a mongoose object like it was just now created.

**app.js**

```
require(`${process.env.APP_DIR}/init/db`)();
console.log(require('mongoose')); // Not a single model in it
```

When normally starting the app, there are no problems here, but because I've also written DB unit tests, it's crashing on them with the error

```
  throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
  ^
  MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
  Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Comment: You need to call the loadSchema from unit test as well.

Comment: The whole app is loaded and started from the unit test since it's a single test call with both routing and unit tests

Comment: I think I've found the problem...
I tried using process.env.PWD somewhere and it all works, except for Mongoose. Deleted it's usage and everything suddenly works. Can someone explain why?